# SQL Server merging rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

About SQL Server rows question.

I want to merge rows as follows:

[[image: picture 1]]

What will merge the results as follows?

[[image: picture 2]]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a straightforward `GROUP BY`, except with Aggregate Text Concatenation of the `ClassTime` field.

Unfortunately SQL Server does not have a built-in aggregate text concatenation function, and the workarounds are not pretty: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

You're probably better-off selecting non-aggregate data and doing the aggregation in your database client software. This is probably the best solution anyway, as text concatenation is a view-concern, not a data-concern, and there is no way you can reliably concatenate text in SQL in a way that's acceptable for all use-cases (e.g. string join separation, culture-awareness, etc).